# Looking for a character rig equal to AnimSchools Malcom quality, or high quality cartoonish human rig

Tags: animation, rigging

Trying to find a high quality cartoony human male rig. Looking for help. Also a working skateboard rig would be nice, im using the new version of blender 2.80 beta, and the skateboard rigs from blendswap dont work with the beta blender version. hmm... basically i have a little animation/film i have in mind i would like to make and would like to use the new version of blender to get used to it. thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Malcom seems to have pretty complicated face setup not sure if I've seen readily available blender rig like that around... I guess BlenRig is the closest? (Not sure if that has been updated for 2.8, though)

https://cloud.blender.org/p/blenrig/